# Applying Martin's Axiom to Families of functions

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The goal is to prove that $\mathsf{MA}$ implies the following. Let $\{ f_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ be some family of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$ of size $<2^{\aleph_0}$. Then, there is a function $f:\omega \to \omega$ that is eventually above all $f_{\alpha}$, i.e. ther exists an $N < \omega$ such that $\forall n > N$, $f(n) > f_{\alpha}(n)$.

This seems like an application of Booth's Lemma which states

> Let $\{A_\alpha \subset \omega: \alpha \in Y\}$ be a family of subsets of $\omega$ with size less than $<2^{\aleph_0}$. If, for each finite subset $F \subset Y$, we have $\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} A_{\alpha}$ being infinite, then there exists a subset $A \subset \omega$ such that $A \setminus A_{\alpha}$ is finite for all $\alpha \in Y$.

I'm aware that $\mathsf{MA}$ implies Booth's Lemma, and my intuition seems to be the fact that $A \setminus A_{\alpha}$ being finite as this seems to be the desired result if we can translate $A$ to the function $f$, $A_{\alpha}$ as the functions $f_{\alpha}$, and the fact that $A \setminus A_{\alpha}$ is finite to $f$ is less than $f_{\alpha}$ on only finitely many values. One issue that I'm coming across when trying to set this up is the fact that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} A_{\alpha}$ must be infinite.

Any hints on how to get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the key points in using forcing axioms is identifying a suitable forcing notion, and a suitable collection of dense open sets.

Here, the forcing notion is easy: Hechler reals. Namely, a forcing condition is an ordered pair, $(p,F)$ where $p$ is a finite function $p\colon n\to\omega$ for some $n<\omega$, and $F$ is a finite family of functions $\omega\to\omega$. The order is defined by $(q,F')\leq(p,F)$ if $p\subseteq q$ and for any $f\in F$, and any $n$ in the domain of $q\setminus p$, $q(n)>f(n)$.

It is easy to see that this forcing notion satisfies the countable chain condition: if $F$ and $F'$ are two finite families of functions, then $(p,F)$ and $(p,F')$ are compatible. In other words, incompatibility can only be achieved by changing the stem/working part/Cohen part; and there are only countably many of those.

And so, we are left to find suitable dense open sets, but that's fairly immediate: just take $D_f$ to be all the conditions which extend $(\varnothing,\{f\})$.

Finally, apply Martin's Axiom.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain . The idea here, as in many similar problems, is that a forcing condition, or a certain part of it, is thought of as a finite approximation to the desired object.  $(p,F)$ "says" that $p$ is a subset of some $f$ such that if $n>\sup dom(p)$ and $h\in F$  then $ f(n)>h(n).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Great explanation. Thank you. This finite approximation approach was much clearer to me in the forcing notion used for Cohen reals. But I'm now happy to be exposed to forcing nations of this form. It seems much easier to prove ccc with these types.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain . In some more difficult problems we need to apply the $\Delta$-system lemma to a set of finite partial functions, or to the set of their domains, to prove ccc.